# MSBuild - how do I exclude directories starting with _resharper?

Tags: msbuild

I'm trying to create an archive with msbuild and I can't seem to be able to exclude the resharper folder.

How should the rule excluding all directories that begin with _resharper look ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm .. it seems that I found it :

```
<DefaultExclude Include="**\_ReSharper.*\**" />
```